# three.js - object look at mouse

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ok I understand it seems I did not try hard enough but I am really new to this
and I get no errors what so ever in Dreamweaver.

I deleted my old example and this is what I have now, trying to integrate
the look at function with the OBJ loader, camera and lights.

I think I understand what is happening more or less in the code,
but it's still not working, I assume it's because there is a code for
window resize but the look at function dose not take that into account,
thus it's not working since the function assume a fixed window size,
Am I right here?

Also I am not sure I need the two commented lines in the obj loader
object.rotateX(Math.PI / 2); and object.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
since this is just to get the starting position?
if I put these tow lines back, it will just rotate the object into an initial pose but the object will not turn relative to mouse position.

I am really not sure what is conflicting here

I changed the code now to this:

```
<script>

var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var camera, scene;
var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;

var container, mesh, geometry, plane;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1500);
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.z = 100;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.lookAt({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
    });

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // LIGHTS
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666, 0.23));

    var light;

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffc1c1, 2.20);
    light.position.set(0, 100, 0);
    light.position.multiplyScalar(1.2);

    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

    light.shadowMapWidth = 512;
    light.shadowMapHeight = 512;

    var d = 50000;

    light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
    light.shadowCameraRight = d;
    light.shadowCameraTop = d;
    light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

    light.shadowcameranear = 0.5;
    light.shadowCameraFar = 1000;
    //light.shadowcamerafov = 30;
    light.shadowDarkness = 0.1;

    scene.add(light);

    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setPath( 'model/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'rope.mtl', function( materials ) {
                    materials.preload();
                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.setPath( 'model/' );
                    objLoader.load( 'rope.obj', function ( object ) {

            var positionX = 0;
            var positionY = 0;
            var positionZ = 0;

          object.position.x = positionX;
          object.position.y = positionY;
          object.position.z = positionZ;
          object.scale.x = 1;
          object.scale.y = 1;
          object.scale.z = 1;
          //object.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);

          //object.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

          // castshow setting for object loaded by THREE.OBJLoader()
          object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
              child.castShadow = true;
              child.receiveShadow = true;
            }
          });

          scene.add(object);
            });
        });



    // RENDERER
    //webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
    });
    webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
    webglRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    webglRenderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
    //webglRenderer.antialias: true;

    container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove, false);

var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), 0);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3();

function onmousemove(event) {
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, intersectPoint);
    object.lookAt(intersectPoint);
}       

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

    </script>
```

Comment: What is your error?  What does it do that you do not expect?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what to expect, 
I am not a programmer by any means.

Depending on where I place the small code snipet, when I publish
it's either not working (i.e the mouse move and object look at) but everything else works fine (ie. the model loads, lights working, camera view so on..)

Or it will break the whole thing and will just show white screen.

I don't see any error message either way.
I use Dreamweaver CC

Comment: I updated my post, I hope this is more clear now.
sorry if it seems I am not trying hard enough, this is all very new to me.

Comment: So I understand that in this community if you are not a real programmer no body will take you seriously, saying you don't put any effort into it despite the fact I sit on it whole night trying all kind of thing.

You assume people don't put any effort because they are new to this
and you have no problem dissing them instead of giving them a general direction. I did not ask for an answer how to do things but instead just a nudge in the right direction.

Just because someone is not a coder and he is having a hard time understanding something dose not mean he don't put any effort.

Comment: Remember that this community will not answer unless it has something useful to contribute.  I looked at it a bit, but did not find a valid answer.  Maybe the group of users of that library is small or does not use SO?

Comment: Thanks Nic, not saying anything personal about you or this question,
it's just the general vibe I get from reading other posts as well.

Trying to combine two or more, code snippets from different places is hard for me, and I can't wrap my head around what to show here from all the codes I tried. for simplicity sake I show only my combined code
which obviously do not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and adapted so it doesn't require a obj and put it into this [codepen](https://codepen.io/igin/pen/jaNdLJ). The main problem seems to be that your intersection plane was defined incorrectly. The first argument is the normal vector which needs to be of length 1. Yours is 0. Therefore there are no meaningful intersections.

```
var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), 0);
```

If you change it to

```
var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 10);
```

the intersections are more meaningful and the object actually rotates.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. thing is I need the obj not just s random primitive.
I compared your code with mine and I see the only difrences are the plane vector and the ommision of the objloader.

But the minute I put back the obj I get a white screen.
No errors in the code.

So I don't know really how to proceed.

Comment: I also had to make the object variable a global variable.

Comment: maybe the object is just so large that it covers the whole screen?

Comment: Not really, here you can see the object (it's a different test i did
so it's just rotating but it is the same model with the same positioning, size and so on

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets.parastorage.com/marketingstudio/webgl_test/test02/rope_model_02.html

It's just an obj with diffuse and bump textures. not very complex as well

Comment: just tried your example and added the lookat stuff and it works as expected. the problem is that in your onmousemove function you reference the object variable which is only available in the load handler. you should add a global variable rope and set rope =object in the load handler. then use this rope variable in the mousemove handler.

Comment: GOT IT! Thank you so much it works!

So the object was a private variable inside the loader function?
So any variable that is not declared at the beginning of the document  outside of any function is not a global variable?

Do I get that right?

Comment: You should read a bit about variable scopes and closures in JavaScript. They are a bit complicated. But generally yes: In this case 'object' is the argument of the load callback. Arguments have function scope, so its only valid inside that function. Google to find more information on JavaScript variables.

Comment: Also it would be great if you could accept my answer ;)

Comment: Of course, answer accepted!
Again thank you, will defiantly read about it more